# How to move the 2 buttons at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

Hey how can I move the two button at the bottom of the page (justified to the bottom and no space between bottom and the button)
Thx in Advance

HTML

```
<ion-content class="background">

       <button ion-button full color="primary"> LOGIN </button>
       <button ion-button full color="danger"> REGISTER </button>


    </ion-content>
```

SCSS

```
page-home {


     .background{
        background-color: #66CC81;
}

.button{
    margin: 0px;

    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-block-end: 0px;

}


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZEN0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following CSS style rule:

```
.button{
    text-align: bottom; 
    position : relative; 
    top: 5px; 
    left: 10px;
    right:20px;
}
```

Comment: thx that worked I just had to use other parameters.                              .button{ 
    text-align: bottom;
    position : relative; bottom: -463px; Left: 0px; Right:0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you will probably get on better if you use `ion-footer`. Put this after your closing `</ion-content>` tag

```
<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
       <button ion-button full color="primary"> LOGIN </button>
       <button ion-button full color="danger"> REGISTER </button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add

position: absolute;

To .button class.